# Can we query all UPS Shipments at once using API

Tags: api, ups

I know, we have dedicated [API documentation](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US) for Shipping and different services.

But there is no endpoint to get all UPS Shipments at once using API.

Can anyone provide me the endpoint with example?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question and after a long email thread with UPS Support they confirmed there is no way to grab historical shipment information.

The only option they gave is maybe using QVM which also has it's limitations.

*That would be correct, Quantum View Manage and Quantum View Data would be your best available option to view the outbound information. You can have it build a report with address, name and tracking number. Contact your local UPS Account Representative for in depth details if you would like to explore that option. There is a Quantum View API however it would first need to be setup via your local Rep with the website. You are still manually searching the docs however for the information at hand when reviewing the reports. It will not pull it up or give a simple error if what you are looking for is not found. They just pull information all or nothing.*